# Inline Check is Required Attribute set

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a DTO let's say:

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    [Required]
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use the `Required`attribute to display an Asterisk in a Blazor Form. Currently I use the following Extension Method:

```cs
public static bool IsRequired(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var objectType = obj.GetType();
    var property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found on type '{objectType.Name}'");
    }

    return property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any();
}
```

This works but it is quite a hassle to call it each time:

```cs
_myDto.IsRequired(nameof(MyDto.MyProperty1))
```

Is there a way to get this directly from the property? What I want (but am open to even simpler solutions) is to call:

```cs
_myDto.MyProperty1.IsRequired();
```

Important is that it should be independent of the type of the property, so it should work with `string`, `int`, Enums,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a way of doing this nicely unless you want to go the route of generating code as a step in your build process similar to PostSharp. I believe the closest you can get, although a bit ugly, without that is something like this:

```cs
public static bool IsRequired<T>(this object source, [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(source))] string memberExpression = null)
{
    if (memberExpression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(memberExpression));

    var memberName = memberExpression?.Split(".").LastOrDefault();
    var sourceType = typeof(T);
    var property = sourceType.GetProperty(memberName);
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The expression '{memberExpression}' does not point to a property on type '{sourceType.Name}'");
    }

    return property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any();
}
```

You'll have to explicitly state the type of the DTO when calling it:

```cs
_myDto.MyProperty1.IsRequired<MyDto>()
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JoCkn7).